# Internet Explorer or Edge:- How To display the warning that appear if you open Custom Protocol Handler again

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, protocol-handler

When i click on a custom link such as **foo:\** , and there is already a registered protocol handler on windows machine, Internet explorer or Edge display a warning before allowing user to run the custom protocol handler, but if the user select to not display this warning again, the Internet explore(Edge) run the protocol handler without displaying the warning. My question is how reset my selection again and make Internet Explorer or Edge display the warning again.

Comment: any help for this question

Answer (score 2):

If the name of your protocol is foo, then you can update the registry with the following:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\foo]
"WarnOnOpen"=dword:00000001
```

Will **enable** it

and

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\foo]
"WarnOnOpen"=dword:00000000
```

will **disable** it

Answer (score 0):

To add on Raj Rao answer: use instead `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute` to install your protocol for all users.

Answer (score -1):

Revert the changes triggered by overriding the protocol handler by finding the event and reverting the state changes to their defaults:

> After updating the registry keys, the program should broadcast the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message with wParam = 0 and lParam pointing to the null-terminated string "Software\Clients\ClientTypeName" to notify the operating system that the default client has changed.

In `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, revert the default data of the protocol in question.

> This registry hierarchy replaces the existing mailto registry hierarchy found at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto. The hierarchy remains the same, only the location has changed.

**References**

- [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa767914)
- [Registering Programs with Client Types (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144109#sample_mail_program)
- [WM_SETTINGCHANGE message (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497)
- [Windows registry information for advanced users](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/256986)
- [How to suppress or display a warning message when users try to save a file in OpenDocument Format (ODF) in Office 2010 or the 2007 Office suite Service Pack 2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/970020)
- [You are prompted to specify Internet Explorer when you click a link in Outlook 2010 or Outlook 2007](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3094186)
- [Windows registry information for advanced users](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/256986)
- [If you don’t want the changes to be permanent, the don’t pass the flag that says that you want the changes to be permanent – The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160721-00/?p=93925)

Comment: This is not answering the question at all. The question is about how to reset suppressed warning dialogs when launching a protocol handler.