# Chromium Edge:- How To display the warning that appear if you open Custom Protocol Handler again

Tags: microsoft-edge

I set the following with reference to 
[Internet Explorer or Edge:- How To display the warning that appear if you open Custom Protocol Handler again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702082/internet-explorer-or-edge-how-to-display-the-warning-that-appear-if-you-open-c), so that the Edge warning screen was not displayed when the custom protocol was executed.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\foo]
"WarnOnOpen"=dword:00000000
```

After installing Microsoft Edge version 79 (Chronium Edge), this setting no longer works.

What should I do to get the same behavior (the Edge warning screen was not displayed)?

Comment: I try to find and check the registry related documents for MS Edge Chromium browser. I did not get any document which shows that whether the old key should work or new key needs to set specifically for Edge browser. I will try to discuss this issue with other engineers and try to know their feedback about this issue. If I get any useful information then I will try to inform you. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such settings for Microsoft Edge(Chromium). I searched through all the settings and only find one related setting. If you don't want the warning to show up again you can set [ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#externalprotocoldialogshowalwaysopencheckbox):

> This policy controls whether the "Always open" checkbox is shown on external protocol launch confirmation prompts.
>
> If you set this policy to True, when an external protocol confirmation prompt is shown, the user can select "Always open". The user won’t get any future confirmation prompts for this protocol.
>
> If you set this policy to False, or the policy is unset, the "Always open" checkbox isn’t displayed. The user will be prompted for confirmation every time an external protocol is invoked.

And you may need to refer to [Configure Policy Settings on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge#configure-policy-settings-on-windows) for how to set the Policy for Microsoft Edge(Chromium).