# Chrome/Firefox:- How To display the prompt that appear if you open Custom Protocol Handler again

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, registry, custom-protocol

This question is top up on question asked by @yo2011 [Internet Explorer or Edge:- How To display the warning that appear if you open Custom Protocol Handler again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702082/internet-explorer-or-edge-how-to-display-the-warning-that-appear-if-you-open-c)

When i click on a custom link such as foo:\ , and there is already a registered protocol handler on windows machine, Chrome/Firefox display a warning before allowing user to run the custom protocol handler, but if the user select to not display this warning again, the Chrome run the protocol handler without displaying the warning. My question is how reset my selection again and make Chrome/Firefox display the warning again.

Also can I remove the checkbox or forget the decision even after remembering asking for "Always allow to open links of these type in the associate app" ?

Resetting all settings in chrome is helping in making the prompt appear again.